# Meaning of bottle her back up

Tags: meaning

I need help with a word in some part of the book Born to Run by Christopher McDougall (Random House, 2018)

> The Tarahumara immediately gave chase. The two canny old vets,
> Sebastiano and Herbolisto, boxed Jenn in from the front while the
> three other Tarahumara surrounded her on the sides. Jenn looked for a
> gap, then burst loose and pulled away. Instantly, the Tarahumara
> swarmed and bottled her back up.

I can't understand what is the meaning of "bottle her back up"?

Comment: ... boxed her in again.

Comment: It looks like it means “surrounded her”, depending on the wider context. She’s not a genie, is she?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It's odd that we can say that, whereas it seems virtually impossible to talk about having ***bottled** her in again*, even facetiously.

Comment: Note that [*the police had **kettled** them in*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22kettled+them+in%22) is the new kid on the block here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We box in, we bottle up. Go figure.

Comment: @DavidK Bottles do tend to fill fairly uniformly vertically.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- But you usually pour the contents _into_ the bottle by letting them flow _downward._

Comment: @DavidK If you are looking at the top line of the liquid in a bottle, as you pour contents, the line goes _up_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Instantly, the Tarahumara swarmed and bottled her back up.

The verb is "to bottle  up", e.g.

*We bottled him up.*

You can think of this as metaphor of keeping something confined inside a bottle.

---

The word *back* is not part of the verb - it is an adverb. It means roughly "again" or "once more", e.g.

**We bottled her back up** means **We bottled her up again/once more.**

---

A stricter definition of this sense of *back*, is given here:

> back
>
> adverb
>
> 2. so as to return to an earlier or normal position or condition: "she put the book back on the shelf" https://languages.oup.com/

Answer (score 9):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottle)

> bottle
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1b to put or keep in a position or situation that makes free activity,
> progress, or escape difficult or impossible —usually used with *up*

So, approximately:

> got her back into a position where escape was impossible

Answer (score -1):

I can't help but think the bottling up is a different idea than the surrounding actions of the group. One bottles up a wild spirit or Genii. Her name *is* Jenn. One surrounds and captures the escaped fugitive. It looks to me as if they went overboard with the descriptions of surrounding, blocking off gaps and closing in. Finally when the capture is on he cannot help but use the bottle up description.